# Failed to load ad 0 in native ad

Tags: android, admob

I am using  native `Admob` ad for android app but everytime i am getting 
    `Failed to load ad : 0`
    when i used addTestDevice(deviceId) is working fine.

**My Code:**

```
private void refreshAd(boolean requestAppInstallAds, boolean requestContentAds, final LinearLayout mLayout) {
        AdLoader adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(mContext, Config.ADMOB_AD_UNIT_ID)
                .forAppInstallAd(new NativeAppInstallAd.OnAppInstallAdLoadedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAppInstallAdLoaded(NativeAppInstallAd appInstallAd) {
                        // Show the app install ad.
                        NativeAppInstallAdView adView = (NativeAppInstallAdView) ((AppCompatActivity) mContext).getLayoutInflater()
                                .inflate(R.layout.ad_app_install, null);
                        populateAppInstallAdView(appInstallAd, adView);
                        mLayout.removeAllViews();
                        mLayout.addView(adView);
                    }
                })
                .forContentAd(new NativeContentAd.OnContentAdLoadedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onContentAdLoaded(NativeContentAd contentAd) {
                        // Show the content ad.
                    }
                })
                .withAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                        // Handle the failure by logging, altering the UI, etc.
                        Log.d("Opennaukri","errorCode = "+errorCode);
                    }
                })
                .withNativeAdOptions(new NativeAdOptions.Builder()
                        // Methods in the NativeAdOptions.Builder class can be
                        // used here to specify individual options settings.
                        .build())
                .build();

        adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

//                .addTestDevice("E9990FA9258AD0601F492495AC3F15EB").build());
//                // Check the LogCat to get your test device ID
//                .addTestDevice("B7BEE8B7CDBAC269CBB598F9DB6C4769")
//                 Check the LogCat to get your test device ID

    }

    private void populateAppInstallAdView(NativeAppInstallAd nativeAppInstallAd,
                                          NativeAppInstallAdView adView) {
        adView.setHeadlineView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_headline));
//        adView.setImageView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_image));
        adView.setBodyView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_body));
        adView.setCallToActionView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_call_to_action));
        adView.setIconView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_app_icon));
        adView.setPriceView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_price));
        adView.setStarRatingView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_stars));
        adView.setStoreView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_store));

        // Some assets are guaranteed to be in every NativeAppInstallAd.
        ((TextView) adView.getHeadlineView()).setText(nativeAppInstallAd.getHeadline());
        ((TextView) adView.getBodyView()).setText(nativeAppInstallAd.getBody());
        ((TextView) adView.getCallToActionView()).setText(nativeAppInstallAd.getCallToAction());
        ((ImageView) adView.getIconView()).setImageDrawable(nativeAppInstallAd.getIcon()
                .getDrawable());


        // Some aren't guaranteed, however, and should be checked.
        if (nativeAppInstallAd.getPrice() == null) {
            adView.getPriceView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            adView.getPriceView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((TextView) adView.getPriceView()).setText(nativeAppInstallAd.getPrice());
        }

        if (nativeAppInstallAd.getStore() == null) {
            adView.getStoreView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            adView.getStoreView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((TextView) adView.getStoreView()).setText(nativeAppInstallAd.getStore());
        }

        if (nativeAppInstallAd.getStarRating() == null) {
            adView.getStarRatingView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            ((RatingBar) adView.getStarRatingView())
                    .setRating(nativeAppInstallAd.getStarRating().floatValue());
            adView.getStarRatingView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        // Assign native ad object to the native view.
        adView.setNativeAd(nativeAppInstallAd);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps to see ads in your app:

1) add internet permision in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

2) In the Gradle file insert this line within dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
```

3) now we need to display the add so we add these few lines in the layout
anyLayout xmlns:android...
 xmlns:ads = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
...

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx.">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

4) finally we need to load the ad in the layout, which only requires 3 lines:

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

If you run the app from the emulator or you check in the layout editor (in android studio) you will see how you ad will look like. If everythings goes right in the layout editor you will see a white banner with "ads by google" (or something like that) and if you run the app in the emulator a dummy banner will show up.

Once you build the apk (signed or unsigned) and install it on a device you won't see any ad yet because google admob need some time between you register a new app to deliver ads and when the ads start to appear (<12h).

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is banner ad but i am using advance native ad and getting problem.i am using same step but always time getting same problem.How to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I had success with the following code:

```
private LinearLayout mAdContainer;
private NativeExpressAdView mAdmobAdView;
private AdRequest mAdmobAdRequest;

[...]

private void loadAds() {
    // find out the width of the device in dp
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float deviceWidthInDp = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;

    int adWidth = (int)(deviceWidthInDp);

    mAdContainer.removeAllViews();
    mAdmobAdView = new NativeExpressAdView(this);
    mAdmobAdView.setAdSize(new AdSize(adWidth, 250)); // AdSize(width, height), height ranges from 80 to 1200
    mAdContainer.addView(mAdmobAdView);
    mAdmobAdView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_id)); // set your admob id
    mAdmobAdRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();
    mAdmobAdView.loadAd(mAdmobAdRequest);
}
```